# submit a comment form with jquery that has multiple id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, forms

I have the the following form below in jquery

```
  ' <form class="form comment_form" role="form" id="'+this._id+'" name="comment-form" action="/users/reply" method="post">'+
            '<div class="form-group">'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="'+this._id+'"/> ' +
            '<input class="form-control col-lg-12 red" style="width:100%" type="text" name="user_comment" placeholder="Your comments" />'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="form-group">'+
            '</div>'+
            '</form>' +
```

I am trying to submit the form but it has a specific id. The form is just an input field and i would just like to submit it when the user press enter. Similar to Facebook. My problem is how do i let the user submit a specific form by just pressing the enter button?

Comment: All the form id are unique. (id="'+this._id+')

Comment: Just add an `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` in your code & it will submit the form on Enter button

Comment: Thanks @ManishYadav but Im trying to use jquery to submit the form so when the enter button is pressed, the page shouldn't refresh. I m trying to use the e.which statement but selecting the the specific form im not familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id need to be unique.Also a form with submit button is useful to trigger `submit` on hitting enter

```
'<form class="form comment_form" role="form" id="' + this._id + '" name="comment-form" action="/users/reply" method="post">' +
  '<div class="form-group">' +
  '<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="input_' + this._id + '"/> ' +
  '<input class="form-control col-lg-12 red" style="width:100%" type="text" name="user_comment" placeholder="Your comments" />' +
  '</div>' +
  '<div class="form-group">' +
  '</div>' +
  '<div><button type="submit">Submit</button></div>'+
  '</form>'
```

Alternately if there is no submit button , you can use javascript/jquery to submit the form

```
$("body").find("#yourFormId").find('input').keypress(function(e) {
  // check for enter/return
  if (e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
    $("body > #yourFormId").submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply  @brk seems like a good aproach but how do i find the specific id for the form

Comment: Thanks again for that solution it help me to find the correct approach. I found the class name for the form and use the this keyword to find the other elements of the form

Answer (score 0):

I successfully found the answer to my question. what in did was that i used the this keyword to find other elements of the form.

```
var form = $('form.comment_form');
    form.on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var input = $(this).find('input[type=text]'),
    comment_id = $(this).find('input[name=post_id]');
    })
```